# Unable to Download App + App is No Longer Available

Tags: ios, deployment, enterprise, ios-provisioning

We have an app that was distributed using Enterprise Distribution Profile. Now, the same app is working for some but others are reporting the following issues.

- Existing/Installed app throws this error, and doesn't open:

  > {App Name} Is No Longer Available
- Users who try to download the app from the Enterprise link are reporting this error:

  > Unable to Download App - {App Name} could not be installed at this time.
  >
  > <kbd>Done</kbd> <kbd>Retry</kbd>

Users running iOS 8.4.1 are specifically reporting these issues. I regenerated the profile and rebuild the app. This seems to have fixed the issue for some users, but not for all.

What's the real problem here? Thoughts?

Comment: have u recently renewed or updated the license?

Comment: Yes, we had to, when iOS 9.1 Beta came out.

Comment: On the devices that are not working, is the date/time correct.  Sometimes we get download errors when the date and time are off, causing problems with the https connection for downloading the ipa.  Basically, if the time is incorrect, it cannot verify the certificate for the https connection, so it fails.

Comment: You'll have to try to perform an install and look at the device console for more details.  Post those and we can try to help.

Answer (score 5):

Most common causes of this issue:

> - URL in the plist that references the ipa is invalid.
> - Device storage is full
> - The provisioning profile is a developer provisioning profile
> - The ad hoc distribution provisioning profile is corrupted and the device is having an issue with it.
> - The device was restored from a backup and is causing a conflict for over-the-air distribution
> - There was a network timeout
> - Architecture settings of the build and the device are incompatible (can sometimes happen when "Build Active Architecture Only" is on when
>     building).
> - Not Using Mobile Safari.

To find out the exact cause of this issue:

> - Connect the device to your Mac.
> - In Xcode, open the Devices window.
> - Choose your device from list on the left.
> - View the console for the device.
> - Now install the app it will show the exact cause of problem

My guess, since it is only happening on some device, is that you could be using a developer provisioning profile, or maybe you are building for only one architecture, so it will only work on some devices that match the built architecture.

Please look at the device console during an install attempt to get a detailed error that should point you down the correct path for a fix.

Comment: We are also getting this error and suspect that it could be that our developer licence has expired. Is that also a likely cause?

Comment: Yes, if your developer account has expired, the certificate associated with that account will no longer be valid and your builds will no longer work.

Comment: Thanks Wottle. Yeah I had assumed that an expired licence would mean new builds would no longer be possible, but it seems that downloads/installs and even existing apps are also disabled. Seems that we need to keep renewing our licence for an old legacy app to keep functioning.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. existing installs will stop running, and new installs will fail. You will need to maintain your account and rebuild each year to keep legacy apps functioning.

Comment: Brilliant with the device console.  It notified me that I needed to trust the provisioning profile.  Normally, I'd get a popup telling me that.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem. 
We have found a temporary solution.

To install beta builds we are installing our apps via itunes and an ipa file