# enterprise app error message "Appname is no longer Available"

Tags: ios, enterprise

I have an enterprise app which is currently being used widely in my organisation however today some of my users received this error message when attempting to open the app "(app name) is no longer available".

I searched the internet trying to find relative information without any success, the closest i could find was that a provisional profile or certificate had expired, so i checked both and can confirm all of them are in date and valid.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening and how i can solve it? short of re-installing on every device which is going to take a very long time.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in your own device? The better thing to do is connect your device in your Mac and have a look in the console to see what's really happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Download App + App is No Longer Available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577621/unable-to-download-app-app-is-no-longer-available)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem on my own device and it appears to be occurring to only a few people. The main problem is that all of these employees are teleworkers all over the world and so getting access to one of the devices to look at the logs is very very difficult.

Comment: I understand. However, if you are in direct contact with them, is it possible to have more details? As model, iOS version, ... to find a common point. Are you using a MDM to distribute your app?

Comment: I have checked out the previous mentioned possible duplicate however that one does not actually contain a confirmed answer to the query and appears to have confirmed an answer for the reason. I will however double check everything they have listed in the other question and see if there is any resemblance to what i am experiencing

Comment: They are running iOS versions 8.4 to 9.1 on iPad Mini 1's. We are using an IPA file to install locally and then sending out to individual people.

Comment: I have a new version of our app which i can install onto there devices which solves the problem however i specifically want to know what caused the problem in the first place so as to prevent it from happening again in the future.

Comment: Yes, sure. I find this post http://support.sprint.com/support/article/Troubleshoot-issues-related-to-apps-on-your-Apple-iPad-mini/WTrendTroubleshootingGuide_542_GKB48266-dvc6750005prd#!/ but I really don't know if it could help, because it's just offering solutions but nothing to prevent.