# App Is No Longer Available

Tags: ios

After install application on mobile device, and change the time of device for one week before. and Try to open app its say `"MyAppName" Is No Longer Available.`

Any one face this issue please let me know, your inputs are appreciable.

Comment: there must be a code signing > provisioning profile issue  ..your certificates may expired kindly check ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to Download App + App is No Longer Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577621/unable-to-download-app-app-is-no-longer-available)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have lot of reasons for this

> - if you don't have an active developer license
> - URL in the plist that references the ipa is invalid.
> - Device storage is full
> - The provisioning profile is a developer provisioning profile
> - The ad hoc distribution provisioning profile is corrupted and the device is having an issue with it.
> - The device was restored from a backup and is causing a conflict for over-the-air distribution
> - There was a network timeout
> - Architecture settings of the build and the device are incompatible (can sometimes happen when "Build Active Architecture Only" is on when
>     building).
> - Not Using Mobile Safari.

This is for found out the issue

> - Connect the device to your Mac.
> - In Xcode, open the Devices window.
> - Choose your device from list on the left.
> - View the console for the device.
> - Now install the app it will show the exact cause of problem

Sources say

['App Name' is No Longer Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646382/app-saysno-longer-available)

[App is no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577621/unable-to-download-app-app-is-no-longer-available)

[Developer.apple.com](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17949)

Comment: Could also be that they set up a profile for the app name in itunes connect, and did nothing with it for a year.  If you let it lapse then you lose  the ability to use that name,  I can't remember if it was for a year, or perminent

Comment: Instead of reposting [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577621/unable-to-download-app-app-is-no-longer-available), you should vote to close as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Any suggested workarounds? I need to be able to move the clock for some device testing

Comment: What happens when in the console, it give Profile missing. Provisioning profile not found.

Comment: What can we do other than reinstallation